# Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath' is deprecated. Please use 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' instead

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

> Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath' is deprecated. Please use
>   'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' instead.

I keep getting this message when running SonarQube through Gradle and the phrase "reportPath" does not even appear even once in the entire multi-module project. I even put the sonarqube property under allprojects to override any defaults that may be there. Any tips on how I can get rid of this error?

I am using:

```
allprojects {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

Gradle wrapper 3.1

Am using this in the root of build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "jacoco"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"
}
```

And tried your suggestion with

```
allprojects {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", ""
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
        }
    }
}
```

No dice, what do you think?

Comment: which sonarqube gradle plugin version?

Comment: As I mentioned based on the documentation this is set by default by the sonarqube gradle plugin

Comment: Right now you do not need to worry, as this is just an information... It is still working, but will be removed in the future... When this happens the gradle sonar plugin will be updated anyways :)

Comment: Heh, just annoying to see it show up when everything works fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is, which version of the sonarQube gradle plugin you are using:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle

The sonarqube gradle plugin sets some values per default, eg. if you use JaCoCo, which is probably the case, it automatically adds that field, besides the groovy one too.

So generally speaking, you need to wait for an update of the sonarqube gradle plugin, which gets rid of this, and is using the other config value.

Maybe you can also try to override the setting, by setting it to empty like `sonar.jacoco.reportPath=`

Comment: FYI. https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarPropertyComputer.java#L247